# Have can I show a progresss indication when I'm doing my work before the tableview is loaded?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I allow the user to manage records on other views. I set a flag if certain changes are made.

Then on the flag (where the data changes will have an impact) I run some methods / queries which create the data which is used in my table view(s). This workload currently happens in viewWillAppear(s).

This could take a few seconds and I'd like to show my progress indicator view which I wrote today, it uses a transparent view with a activity indicator in the center of the view.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startupStuff) withObject:sender];
```

However, viewWillAppear won't wait while I run the the work in the background.

Ideally I'm looking for a quick fix to work around this problem.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, viewWillAppear won't wait while I run the the work in the background.

That's the whole point of it, isn't it? At the end of your `startupStuff` method, you should call another method on the main thread (with `performSelectorOnMainThread:...`) that is used to (a) inform the controller that your data is ready, (b) reload the table view and (c) dismiss your progress indicator view.